# Nginx is outputting logs to my terminal (stdout). How can I stop it?

Tags: linux, nginx

My laptop is ArchLinux, with Nginx 1.6.2 installed. I’ve never touched Nginx’s log configuration, but out of blue, when I try to access the local website, the logs will be printed to the opening Terminal (if more than one is opening, there’s only one will have it).

I just cant’t figure out why, and how can I locate the problem.

Any answers would be appreciated.

```
# nginx.conf file content
user http;
worker_processes  8;  

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024; 
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on; 
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65; 

    gzip  on; 
    include servers/*.conf;
}
#below is one of the server config file content
server {
listen       80;
server_name  www.laravel.com;

#charset koi8-r;

#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

root   /srv/http/blog/public;

location / {
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
       # fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
       include        fastcgi_params;
    }

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
    #listen       8000;
    #listen       somename:8080;
    #server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #location / {
    #root   html;
    #index  index.html index.htm;
    #}
#}
```

Comment: What is nginx's log config?

Comment: Put it into post. Noone will read this unformatted mess

Comment: @AlexeyTen Sorry, I'd just gotta go this morning. Now it's formatted. In fact, I don't think there's anything to do with the nginx config file. What makes system logs printed out to stdout?

Comment: This is not config. All lines commented out.

Comment: @AlexeyTen OK, here I pasted all my config file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can say, and I'm not sure, cause of the "formating": There is not a single line sayig something like `error_log  /where/should/nging/save/the/error.log;` that is not comment out.

The vhost config should look somewhat like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.laravel.com;
    charset koi8-r;
    access_log  /where/to/put/the/logs/host.access.log  main;
    error_log   /where/to/put/the/logs/host.error.log; # <- LOOK AT THIS LINE
    root   /srv/http/blog/public;
    location / {
        # ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You understand me the most. That's why  I don't think the problem is caused by Nginx configuration.

Comment: Well, please look again at the config I posted. There is a line saying  `error_log ...`. This line is *missing* in your config. So nginx probably don't know where to put the config.